# How to create a tab using Views?

Tags: views

I am using Drupal 7 and I have content type events. It has many node pages created used by events content type.Event names and years are fields in event content type. I want to create years as tabs.When clicks years(tabs)it will show all events names happened in that year. I don't know how to create tabs using views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When creating a page view using views, it gives you the ability to assign a menu for that page, in this situation you can define all views with same parent path like `parent/view1` , `parent/view2`, then in middle box when adding menu item you can select views as `menu tab entry` while `default menu tab` can be assigned for the view you want to be shown when navigating to `parent` path.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [quick tabs](https://www.drupal.org/project/quicktabs) module. With that you can create a quick tab block, and show your view with different arguments as tabs.